# web app doesn't deploy properly

Tags: java, spring, apache, web-services, jax-ws

I'm using tomee 1.6.0 plus. I'm generating code from my wsdl. when I try to deploy my application i get this error in tomee log:

```
Jun 12, 2014 1:59:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet cxf as unavailable
Jun 12, 2014 1:59:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /vezbe-wsdl-ws threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1689)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.LazyStopWebappClassLoader.loadClass(LazyStopWebappClassLoader.java:109)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.JavaeeInstanceManager.newInstance(JavaeeInstanceManager.java:69)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.JavaeeInstanceManager.newInstance(JavaeeInstanceManager.java:64)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:983)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1660)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My cxf-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

<jaxws:endpoint 
    id="helloDoc" 
    address="/HelloDocument"
    implementor="yu.ac.ns.ftn.informatika.ws.hello.HelloDocumentImpl"
    wsdlLocation="WEB-INF/wsdl/HelloDocument.wsdl"/>

<jaxws:endpoint 
    id="address" 
    address="/AddressBook"
    implementor="yu.ac.ns.ftn.informatika.ws.address.AddressBookImpl"
    wsdlLocation="WEB-INF/wsdl/AddressBook.wsdl"/>

 </beans>
```

web.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
    <display-name>cxf</display-name>
    <description>cxf</description>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <display-name>cxf</display-name>
        <description>Apache CXF Endpoint</description>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cxf</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

jars in my classpath:

cxf-2.6.5.jar

jaxb-api-2.2.5.jar

jaxb-impl-2.2.5.1.jar

jaxb-xjc-2.2.5.1.jar

spring-beans-2.5.6.jar

spring-context-2.5.6.jar

spring-core-2.5.6.jar

spring-web-2.5.6.jar

velocity-1.7.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you deactivated cxf (disabled = true) in conf/conf.d/cxf.properties and conf/conf.d/cxf-rs.properties

Another solution is to move spring in tomee container.

Side note: this should work on coming tomee 1.7.0 but JAX-WS services doesn't need spring at all in TomEE+